# Laravel package installation on live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

How to install package in laravel on live server, whenever I run "command composer require monolog/monolog". It gives error Could not open input file: /home/root/composer.phar

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not run `composer require` on live server. You should only run `composer install` so you should require it locally, test if everything is working fine and then on live server just install library that is tested in your application.

About error:

> Could not open input file: /home/root/composer.phar

make sure this file really exists (if not you can download it from Composer site) and make sure it has correct permissions (it should have execute permission) - use `chmod +x composer.phar` to make it executable

Comment: Are you logged as root user? When you run `ls /home/root` do you see `composer.phar` file in there? Does it have execute permission set?

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this.

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ php composer.phar update monolog/monolog
```

You can install package without any problem.